# (5.4-beta-6) Zone event handler isn't called

Tags: java, tapestry

As far as I understand, **Zone** is a component and I can handle it's events.

So I types the following code:

```
@InjectComponent
private Zone zoneSample;
@OnEvent(component = "zoneSample")
private void zoneEvent() {
    System.out.println(String.format("Zone client id: %s", zoneSample.getClientId()));
}
```

No exception is thrown so the **Zone** ID is set correctly. But the event isn't fired !
Shouldn't this event handling method match all events for the zone ?

I expected it to be fired basically before, while and after rendering the zone because I need to see if I can obtain the generated zone's client-id to use it to show this zone later on using the **AjaxResponseRenderer** class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Zone fires no events. There's a handy mixin that can help you in this scenario, the [RenderNotification mixin](http://tapestry.apache.org/5.4/apidocs/org/apache/tapestry5/corelib/mixins/RenderNotification.html).

It provides two events: beginRender and afterRender, I think that's all you need. After you apply the mixin to the zone, the code to handle the events would look something like this:

```
void onBeginRenderFromZoneSample(MarkupWriter writer)
{
    ...
}

void onAfterRenderFromZoneSample(MarkupWriter writer)
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: So a component has a render phase, but it has to trigger it's own events ?

Comment: Yes, and most components do not trigger these events, that's why the RenderNotification mixin is so helpful. I usually look at the top of each component to see which events it may fire (they are defined with the @Events annotation, which is for documentation purposes only).